# mysql query to get data for a particular date in a different format

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table called event that five columns: event_id, Date, timing, event_type_id and capacity.

I am trying to get records from the table event where the date column matches a particular date in the format mm/dd/yyyy

Here's my php code:

```
<?php


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","simple","eventsdb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_GET['date']))
{
$when = $_GET['date'];
}
else{ 
$when = date("d/m/Y");
}

echo $when;

$sql="SELECT Event_id, Date, Capacity FROM event where DATE('Date')='$when'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
 // Fetch one and one row
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
printf ("%s %s %s <br>",$row[0],$row[1],$row[2]);
}
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I think there is something wrong with the sql statement because it returns all the records even those not matching the date value

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am suspecting your query failed but you're not checking for errors and also suspecting your date column type doesn't match the incoming data. Yet, we don't know what the schema is for it.

Comment: `Date` is a reserved word, so I doubt this query is running without `\`` around your column name.

Comment: also shouldn't the format to compare a date be `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: this is the format returned by a jquery calendar. i thought the date function takes into account the different format

Comment: even when I execute this statement : SELECT Event_id, eventdate, Capacity FROM event where DATE('eventdate')='2017-07-27' in mysql, I get no records even though i have two with this date in the table

Comment: You need to post the actual SQL used to create your table, not just "here are the columns"  As @Jeff has indicated, `Date` is a reserved word, i.e., you should ***never*** use it as a column name, and MySQL dates are stored in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, so if you want to do date comparisons, format your input date to match the MySQL date format.

Comment: try something like this  `where MONTH('date') = MONTH($when);` to get the result based on month and there are several date options available 
check this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

From the above example, it should be written sql statement problems.

problems sql:

```
$sql="SELECT Event_id, Date, Capacity FROM event where DATE('Date')='$when'"
```

please change to following:

```
$sql="SELECT Event_id, Date, Capacity FROM event where DATE(Date)='$when'"
```

maybe it's can work,pls try.

in your case DATE('Date') will return NULL,When the return value is NULL, it will be invalidated as a conditional comparison, which is similar to no condition to query or is equivalent to where 1 = 1, as mentioned by returning all records.